# how do I add a zip file to a Junit test in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit, zip

trying to use a zip file in my Junit tests in Eclipse, but Junit test doesn't seem to find the file. What can I do?

Comment: How is it trying to find the file?

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that a step in your unit tests requires opening that zip file and doing something with the contents?

If so, then the zip file has to be in the classpath of the test runner.  If your project is a Maven project, then you would likely have to store the zip file in "src/test/resources".  If it's not a Maven project, then you'll have to make an educated guess of a resonable path to store the file in.  You'll likely need to add that resulting folder as a source folder in the "Build Path" section of the project properties.